# Help me find this verse from Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, itihasa

So I am reading Hindu superiority by Sarda Har Bilas and in that Mr Sarda puts this verse

> Time is the root of all created beings, And uncreated. of pleasure and of pain.
>
> Time creates existence. Time destroys, Time shatters all, and all again renews.
>
> Time watches while all sleep. Unvanquished Time!
>
> —Mahabharata : Adiparva."

If you have read Mahabharata can you pls find the verse number for me? Or does this verse even exist in Mahabharat?

Comment: Page number is 41, and 3 page number in antiquity section (hindu superiority by sarda har bilas)

Answer (score 4):

I have not read it in the Mahabharata but it's quoted in the commentary of a Kularnava Tantram verse. The verse from Mahabharata is quoted there to show that KAla or time is not merely the destroyer but it's the creator as well.

In Sanskrit the verse is as follows:

> KAlah srijati bhutAni kAlah samharate prajAh |
>  samharantam prajAh
> kAlam kAlah shamayate punaha ||

The location of the verses is given as **Mahabharata 1.1.209-210**. It's the [Haridas Siddhantavagis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haridas_Siddhanta_Bagish) Mahabharata ( Edition of Bengali year 1338) they are quoting the verse from.

So, yes such a verse is present in the Mahabharata.

Note that the translation of the Sanskrit verse I have quoted is already found in your question as "Time creates existence. Time destroys, Time shatters all, and all again renews" (this is more or less a correct translation of the Sanskrit verse).

And, therefore, in the edition I'm using as the reference, the location of "Time is the root of all created beings, And uncreated. of pleasure and of pain." will be Mahabharata 1.1.208 and similarly for the remaining one.

Comment: Sir, can you suggest the commentary for kularnav tantra?

Comment: I am reading a Bengali commentary and translation. In English you can find Arthur Avalon's translation. @Rudra You can search. If you can't find it then tell me here.

Comment: thanks. I found it

Comment: Okay ...:) @Rudra

Answer (score 3):

This verse from Mahabharata is quoted in its English translation in a Physics book. This is from **Adi parva 1st chapter, BORI edition.**

kAlamUlamidaM sarvaM bhAvAbhAvau sukhAsukhe || 187||

kAlaH pachati bhUtAni kAlaH saMharati prajAH |
nirdahantaM prajAH kAlaM kAlaH shamayate punaH || 188||

kAlo vikurute bhAvAnsarvA.Nlloke shubhAshubhAn |
kAlaH sa~NkShipate sarvAH prajA visRRijate punaH || 189||

kAlaH sarveShu bhUteShu charatyavidhRRitaH samaH || 189||

atItAnAgatA bhAvA ye cha vartanti sAmpratam |
tAnkAlanirmitAnbuddhvA na sa~nj~nAM hAtumarhasi || 190||